# How does cpu speed stepping effect the cpu usage percentages reported in (for example) htop?

Tags: linux, cpu, top, htop

How does cpu speed stepping effect the cpu usage percentages reported in (for example) htop? How about the normal top?

So, if my cpu is stepped down to 800mhz with a full speed of 2ghz, does 5% used mean that the cpu ran for 0.05 * 800 = 40 million cycles used , or 0.05 *  2000 = 100 million cycles used?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time finding a reasonable explanation for the differences in approach, but here's what I see:

In **Linux**, using `htop`, the CPU utilization percentages are relative to the **current clock speed**. When your CPU is fully stepped down, your close-to-idle background processes might look much busier than they really are, if you compare them to more "active" processes that might run 10 seconds later and cause your CPU to step up.

There's a really good answer here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58541/9854) that explains how this works - basically the system tracks "clock ticks", and htop, for a given span of time, converts that into a percentage by looking at your (instantaneous/at-that-time) clock speed. This methodology seems like it would sometimes yield numbers over 100%, but I guess they must normalize/cap it.

This does *not* seem to be how task manager in **Windows** reports CPU utilization - it seems to focus on usage relative to some "standard" 100% capacity for your CPU (not sure how they decide what 100% is, in a world of overclocking and turbo boost).

One example consequence of this difference is that under exactly identical circumstances, when my CPU has pathologically stepped down to 200MHz as opposed to the normal 900MHz idle and 3600Mhz busy, linux htop reports "CPU capacity maxed out panic panic" while Windows says "Hey, everything's cool, CPU's totally underutilized" even though there isn't enough CPU throughput to keep track of the mouse cursor...

In both places, you can "make sense" of these situations, if you know what you're doing:

- In Windows (10), with "More details" open, you can switch to the Performance tab, CPU section, to see the current CPU frequency
- In Linux with `htop`, set up with <kbd>F2</kbd>, and under "Display Options", check the "Also show CPU frequency" box. This will place the utilization numbers in context.

Answer (score 0):

The stepping is irrelevant. 5% means the CPU cores were doing useful work 5% of the time.

Don't multiply speeds by fractions that way. The numbers you get by doing that are basically meaningless. The "40Mhz" you get is a meaningless number -- nothing happened at 40MHz.

Comment: I never said anything happened at 40Mhz. The cpu usage is measuring how many of the clock cycles were used this period yes? So I'm asking, if top reports 5%, does that mean that the cpu was doing work for 40 million cycles this second, or 100 million cycles. Approximate numbers of course, superscalar pipelined processors etc make it far less simple than that.

Comment: You are right in that I should get my units right and not refer to an _amount_ of cycles as Hertz.

Comment: I don't think what you're doing is meaningful. What information does the 5% not give you that you need?

Comment: Well, it's interesting for trying to get a good idea of what my background load is. For example, if spotify (linux) is using 10% of one core to play music and I can see that the core is at 800mhz - does that mean that spotify is horribly inefficient,or slightly inefficient? - I just did a test with changing my cpu governor to performance and the percentage usage numbers dropped right down, so I guess I have answered my question

Comment: I'm not sure how you could determine usefully if spotify is "efficient" based on that information.

Comment: Well, if you are going to start to answer that question you need to understand what the cpu usage percentages actually mean in the context of speed stepping, hence this question. I think I've determined using  5% of a core while the system is near idle is a very different amount of processing than using 5% of a core while the system is at load.

Comment: Right, but that's due to a number of factors. For example, the other cores will be placing a load on the memory controller, so memory operations will take longer. In most cases, it's not worth trying to account for all these factors because the effort involved is significant and the payoff is near zero.

Comment: I hate to downvote a "rival" answer, but this response is rather unhelpful; of course CPU throughput will be limited by all kinds of interesting things going on in the system - but it is helpful for users to understand when "% CPU" really doesn't mean "% of your CPU's **overall capacity**" but rather "% of your CPU's current **capacity at its current chosen speed**". As noted above MS-Windows, for example, chooses to report CPU utilization per process as the former, not the latter.